# Xcode tvOS - How to detect when the Menu button on TV Remote is pressed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tvos

I'm developing a tvOS app and I'm trying to programmatically detect when the Menu button on the Apple TV Remote is pressed with a tap gesture but the handleTap: won't get called. I show you the code. Is this the right way? Best regards.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check line 25.
I think you should change `UIPressTypeMenu`.

Working version on Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    setupRemoteContoller()
}

func setupRemoteContoller() {
    let menuPressRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    menuPressRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonAction))
    menuPressRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPress.PressType.playPause.rawValue)]
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(menuPressRecognizer)
}

@objc func menuButtonAction() {
    print("The menu button is pressed")
}
```